# How to check if there's two facts that represent the same in prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm having trouble understanding this. Suppose I have:

```
person(peter).
person(bob).
person(amanda).
```

Is there a way in which I can prove that no two persons have the same name?
I tried doing:

```
person(X) = person(Y).
```

but this gives:

```
X = Y
```

or is this enough??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Above you are working with a unary relation `person/1` (the represents the single argument). You define the facts that peter, bob and amanda are persons. Then you are asking Prolog to unify `person(X)` and `person(Y)`, i.e., find the most general values of `X` and `Y` such that the expression holds. Of course we only need have `Y = X` for that hence the reply.

If you want to enforce a condition like that, you would need to represent people by something else than their first names, otherwise they would be implicitly equal.

Say use an id.

```
person(1).
person(2).
person(3).

name(1, peter).
name(2, bob).
name(3, amanda).
```

and then query

```
?- name(Y, X), name(Z, X), Y \= Z.
```

Answer (score 0):

Within the logical core of Prolog, there shouldn't be any distinction between unique and duplicated rules; `person(peter)` is provable or it isn't, and that's the only question that (pure) Prolog can ask.

But stepping outside the logical core, there's a lot more you can do, like arithmetic, and I/O, and tearing your database apart at runtime. That last one comes in especially handy here, since it means we can erase the rule `person(bob).` from the database and then check if it's still provable.

First, to make rules modifiable, we need to declare the functor as dynamic:

```
:- dynamic person/1.
person(peter).
person(bob).
person(amanda).
```

With that done, we can use `retract(person(bob))` to remove a rule, and `assert(person(bob))` to put it back.

Now, if you don't mind trashing your database, all it takes is:

```
has_duplicates :- person(X), retract(person(X)), person(X).
```

But we probably want to leave everything the way we found it, so we'll need to jump through a few hoops:

```
has_duplicates :- person(X), retract(person(X)), assert(backup(X)), person(X), restore.
has_duplicates :- restore, fail.

restore :- backup(X), retract(backup(X)), assert(person(X)), fail.
restore :- true.
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to create a list of the names and test if the list has any duplicates.

```
findall(Name,person(Name),NameList)
```

does the first part.  Then checking for duplicates can be as simple as

```
is_set(NameList)
```

if you use SWI-prolog, for example.  Or check the length of the list before and after sorting (which deletes duplicates).  Or sort the list and run down the list checking for adjacent elements of the list being the same.